# Why kafka-console-consumer.sh does not return messages from all available logs with --from-beginning?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When I use :

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config kafka.properties --bootstrap-server myBroker1:6643,myBroker2:6643  --topic myTopic --from-beginning`

I retrieve approximatly one day of messages despite my logs have 168hours of retention and no size limit.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried other tools like kafkacat? Could you show the earliest available offsets of the topic vs the offsets that get printed?

Comment: When you run this command repeatedly, are you always getting the approx. one day of messages? Or only on the first run and then nothing until new messages get published? Can you show your kafka.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake from my side ... I saw log from one topic and requested another one.

To see the oldest available message in the log :

```
export JAVA_HOME=<Your java Home>
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<Your jaas.conf>"
/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config kafka.properties --bootstrap-server myKafka:6643  --topic myTopic --from-beginning  --max-messages 1
```

kafka.properties:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.location=<your truststore>
ssl.truststore.password=<your truststore password>
```

jaas.conf:

```
KafkaClient {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 useTicketCache=false
 useKeyTab=true
 renewTicket=true
 principal="Your user@DOMAIN"
 keyTab="Your user keytab"
 storeKey=false
 serviceName="kafka";
};
Client {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 useTicketCache=false
 useKeyTab=true
 principal="Your user@DOMAIN"
 keyTab="Your user keytab"
 renewTicket=true
 storeKey=true
 serviceName="zookeeper";
};
```